# How to store a large number of words (to be accessed by an android app)?

Tags: android, database, file-io, dictionary, indexing

I have a list of words (112,000 in alphabetical order) **with one word definitions**. The definitions are sometimes more than one and are in the format:

word:definition1|definition2|...

The **max number of definitions for a word is 8**.

I need a method to store these in a file (or more is okay) so they can be accessed by an android app. Only one word will be accessed at a time. This list will never change.

Considering **SQLite**, how would I insert the large data into a database?

Considering **RandomAccessFile**, how would I create a index for these words?

Is there another way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to go with SQLite as it would be easy to fetch data as and when required and it would be simply easy to get/date/update data from particular position too.

One more benefit is that you can prepare SQLite database by using GUI tool too.

Now follow below procedure to use **Existing SQLite database**, means that you will have database ready with words data:

1. Prepare SQLite database same as we do in .NET , here you can prepare it using one of the best tool **SQLite Manager** which you can download it as a tool/add-on inside Mozilla Firefox.
2. Once you are done with database, simple paste it inside `assets` folder.
3. Now write a code to copy database from `assets` folder into our app. There are plenty of examples available on web for the same.

Comment: This is fantastic. I'm not familiar with .NET. Will you please explain on how to fill the database with data from text file? Briefly and I'll Google it.

Comment: Used vb script in Excel and imported the data and then to SQLite. Thanks!

Comment: @ArjunU If it has helped you really then you should up vote it.

Comment: Cannot do that, yet. My reputation is too low.

Answer (score -1):

Use a sqlite DB , storing 112,000 or more shouldn't be a problem at all for sqlite . 
Your can use your db schema something like the following :

[image]

And there can be multiple entries of wordId -> meaningId , for each word .

for pre-storing data you could use a tutorial provided by me in my blog : [Using Pre-populated sqlite database in android](http://theprogrammersvicodin.blogspot.in/2011/11/using-static-database-with-android.html)

Comment: Yes but my question was how to pre populate the database with 112K words.

Comment: Just edited my answer , please write something in your question like : how do i pre-populate my database .